# how to remove or hide border box of Textarea?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on `JavaFx` trying to round the corner of Textarea just like the area of typing message on the  WhatsApp

I did try with setStyle for all focus and background; border color, faint

```
TextArea area=new TextArea();  
area.setStyle( "-fx-region-background: null;"
         + "-fx-text-box-border: transparent;"
         + "-fx-text-fill:black;"
         + "-fx-border-color:#c6c6c6;"
         + " -fx-border-width: 2;"
         + "-fx-border-radius: 30;"
         + "-fx-control-inner-background: transparent;"
         + "-fx-focus-color: transparent;"
         + "-fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;");
```

this a snap of what I get if i run the code i did succeed to rounded the textarea but sound like still  there is a box on the front  if you notice the four angles

[image]

sound like there is triangle box on front how to remove the border of that triangle

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqzJ.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me give it a shot let me know if thats not what your looking for

Here is how to do it with a CSS file

```
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-radius: 15;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: #c6c6c6;
}
.text-area {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.text-area .viewport{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.text-area .content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]